# Trying to make Minecraft(following tutorial) code not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, minecraft, cube

Here is my Chunk.cs code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    public MeshFilter meshFilter;

    void Start()
    {
        int vertexIndex = 0;
        List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        List<int> triangles = new List<int>();
        List<Vector2> uvs = new List<Vector2>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int triangleIndex = VoxelData.voxelTris[0, 1];
            vertices.Add(VoxelData.voxelVerts [triangleIndex]);
            triangles.Add(vertexIndex);

            uvs.Add(Vector2.zero);

            vertexIndex++;
        }
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        mesh.uv = uvs.ToArray();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals ();

        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
    }

}
```

Here is my VoxelData.cs code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;

public static class VoxelData
{
    public static readonly Vector3[] voxelVerts = new Vector3[8]
    {
        new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
        new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),
        new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f),

    };

    public static readonly int[,] voxelTris = new int[1, 6]
    {
        {3, 7, 2, 2, 7, 6}// Top face
    };
}
```

Here is the tutorial I have been following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h66IN1Pndd0&list=PLVsTSlfj0qsWEJ-5eMtXsYp03Y9yF1dEn&index=1

The error might be something related to the function on line 21, due to it is not yellow like the other add function:

```
vertices.Add(VoxelData.voxelVerts [triangleIndex]);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the error, I have to assume it is this

```
int triangleIndex = VoxelData.voxelTris[0, 1];
```

Which should be

```
int triangleIndex = VoxelData.voxelTris[0, i];
```

if that doesn't fix it then i think you should be more specific about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space between?

```
vertices.Add(VoxelData.voxelVerts[triangleIndex]);
```

Comment: Thanks SyBom , using i instead of 1 worked. Although, there was no error when I ran the code before(when I was using the i).